# Issue with firing one script canceling another script when used before the other

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

So I have a page where one script allows user to copy contents to clipboard and then another angular script that toggles a showing of a text editor. The issue here is if the selects the 'add notes' button (called the ng-click="showEditor"), then the copy to clipboard function ceases to work. Not sure why one is canceling the other. The code:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-74074881-2', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>


<style type="text/css">
    @media screen {
  #printSection {
      display: none;
  }
}

@media print {
  body * {
    visibility:hidden;
  }
  #printSection, #printSection * {
    visibility:visible;
  }
  #printSection {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
  }
}

</style>

<div class="container-fluid" style="font-family: Segoe UI; padding: 0;">
    <div style="background-color: #0070c0; min-height:100px;">
        <h1 style="color: #ffffff; font-size: 24px; padding-left:20px; padding-top: 30px;">Problem Phase Worksheet</h1>
        <span style="float: right; font-size: 14px;"><a href="https://www.moneyball.ms/" target="_self" style="color: #ffffff; padding-right: 25px;">Return to Moneyball Site</a></span>
    </div>
    <form class="form-horizontal" autocomplete="off" role="form" style="padding-left: 20px; padding-top: 20px;">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <span style="color: #0070c0; font-size: 20px;">Inputs</span>
            </div>          
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="criteria" style="font-size: 18px; padding-bottom: 10px;">Criteria:</label>
                <span style="color: #afabab;"><i class="fa fa-question-circle" aria-hidden="true" uib-tooltip=" The threshold at which your hypothesis is considered to be true or false. 
                Examples: “More than 80%”, “Three quarter (75%)”, “Majority (51%-100%)”
                "></i></span>               
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="criteria" ng-model="criteria" style="font-size: 18px;" placeholder="(e.g. more than 80%)">
            </div>              
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="customer" style="font-size: 18px; padding-bottom: 10px;">Customer:</label>
                <span style="color: #afabab;"><i class="fa fa-question-circle" aria-hidden="true" uib-tooltip=" A type of people or organizations to whom eventually you want to offer your product. Note, that sometime in big organizations there is a difference between buyers who purchase a product and end-users who actually use the product.
                Examples: “Enterprise system admins”, “Enterprise IT managers”, “Startup developers”, “Academia Data Scientists”
                "></i></span>               
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="customer" ng-model="customer" style="font-size: 18px;" placeholder="(e.g. enterprise system admins)">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="task" style="font-size: 18px; padding-bottom: 10px;">Job to be done:</label>
                <span style="color: #afabab;"><i class="fa fa-question-circle" aria-hidden="true" uib-tooltip=" The main task for which customers “hire” products and services to get a “job” done. A framework that has been popularized by Clayton Christensen and Anthony Ulwick.
                Examples: 
                “Keeping their servers up to date”, “Planning infrastructure capacity”, “Deploying a mobile app”, “Preparing database for analysis”
                "></i></span>           
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="task" ng-model="task" style="font-size: 18px;" placeholder="(e.g. keeping servers up to date)">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="problem" style="font-size: 18px; padding-bottom: 10px;">Problem:</label>
                <span style="color: #afabab;"><i class="fa fa-question-circle" aria-hidden="true" uib-tooltip=" The major challenge that customers are facing when performing their Job-To-Be-Done. Note that the problem description needs to be specific and measurable. This can help to estimate a size of the problem and it also can be used as a benchmark for a value proposition provided by your new product.  
                Examples:
                “It takes too long (more than 24 hours)”, “It costs too much (more than $10,000)”, “It require too many tools (five)”
                "></i></span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="problem" ng-model="problem" style="font-size: 18px;" placeholder="(e.g. it takes to long (24+ hours) )">
            </div>  
        </div>      
        <div class="col-md-6">   
            <div> 
                <span style="color: #0070c0; font-size: 20px;">Examples</span>
                <a id="btnPrint" class="btn btn-primary" style="float: right; font-size: 18px;">
                    <span><i class="fa fa-print" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>   Print
                </a>
                <a class="btn btn-primary" style="float: right; font-size: 18px; margin-right: 10px;" uib-tooltip="copy to clipboard" ngclipboard data-clipboard-target="#printThis" ng-click="steps.copyToast()">
                    <span><i class="fa fa-files-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>  Copy                 
                </a>                
            </div>              
            <div id="printThis" style="background-color: #ffffff; padding: 15px; margin-top: 20px; border: 1px solid #ccc; border-radius: 8px;" ng-model="problemExp">  <div>
                    <p style="font-size: 18px; color: #afabab; font-weight: 600;">HYPOTHESIS</p>
                    <p style="font-size: 18px;" id="hypCriteria">We believe that <span style="color: blue;">{{ criteria || '[criteria]' }}</span> of <span style="color: blue;">{{ (customer != null) ? customer : '[customer]' }}</span> are most frustrated about <span style="color: blue;">{{ (task != null) ? task : '[job to be done]' }}</span> because <span style="color: blue;">{{ problem || '[problem]' }}</span>.</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p style="font-size: 18px; color: #afabab; font-weight: 600; margin-top: 25px;">CUSTOMER: SCREENING CRITERIA:</p>
                    <p style="font-size: 18px;">We are looking for <span style="color: blue;">{{ (customer != null) ? customer : '[customer]' }}</span> who are regularly involved in <span style="color: blue;">{{ (task != null) ? task : '[job to be done]' }}</span>.</p>
                </div> 
                <div>
                    <p style="font-size: 18px; color: #afabab; font-weight: 600; margin-top: 25px;">EXPERIMENT: INTERVIEW QUESTIONS:</p>
                    <p style="font-size: 18px;">Thank you for your time and interest in sharing your experiences. You are the expert. We are here to learn from you. I’m going to talk as little as possible.</p>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" style="font-size: 18px; margin-bottom: 10px;" ng-click="showEditor()">
                        <span><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>   Add Notes
                    </a>
                    <p style="font-size: 18px;">1. Tell me who is involved in <span style="color: blue;">{{ (task != null) ? task : '[job to be done]' }}</span> at your company?</p>
                    <div ng-hide="isHidden" style="padding-bottom: 25px; margin-left: 20px;">
                        <trix-editor angular-trix ng-model="foo"></trix-editor>                     
                    </div> 
                    <p style="font-size: 18px;">2. How often are you personally involved in <span style="color: blue;">{{ (task != null) ? task : '[job to be done]' }}</span>?</p> 
                    <div ng-hide="isHidden" style="padding-bottom: 25px; margin-left: 20px;">
                        <trix-editor angular-trix ng-model="foo"></trix-editor>                     
                    </div> 
                    <p style="font-size: 18px;">3. Tell me about the last time when you did <span style="color: blue;">{{ (task != null) ? task : '[job to be done]' }}</span>.</p>
                    <div ng-hide="isHidden" style="padding-bottom: 25px; margin-left: 20px;">
                        <trix-editor angular-trix ng-model="foo"></trix-editor>                     
                    </div>                                                  
                    <p style="font-size: 18px;">4. What were the major challenges when you were this task?</p>
                    <div ng-hide="isHidden" style="padding-bottom: 25px; margin-left: 20px;">
                        <trix-editor angular-trix ng-model="foo"></trix-editor>                     
                    </div>                  
                    <p style="font-size: 18px;">5. Which of these challenges did you find most frustrating?</p>     
                    <div ng-hide="isHidden" style="padding-bottom: 25px; margin-left: 20px;">
                        <trix-editor angular-trix ng-model="foo"></trix-editor>                     
                    </div>                              
                    <p style="font-size: 18px;">6. On a scale of 0-10 (where 10 is extremely frustrating), how frustrating was this experience? Why?</p>
                    <div ng-hide="isHidden" style="padding-bottom: 25px; margin-left: 20px;">
                        <trix-editor angular-trix ng-model="foo"></trix-editor>                     
                    </div>                  
                    <p style="font-size: 18px;">7. Have you done anything to work around these challenges? What?</p>
                    <div ng-hide="isHidden" style="padding-bottom: 25px; margin-left: 20px;">
                        <trix-editor angular-trix ng-model="foo"></trix-editor>                     
                    </div>                  
                    <p style="font-size: 18px;">8. If so, how well did that solve your problem? Why/why not?</p>
                    <div ng-hide="isHidden" style="padding-bottom: 25px; margin-left: 20px;">
                        <trix-editor angular-trix ng-model="foo"></trix-editor>                     
                    </div>                  
                    <p style="font-size: 18px;">9. If you could wave a magic wand and be able to do anything about <span style="color: blue;">{{ (task != null) ? task : '[job to be done]' }}</span> in your daily job, what would it be?</p>
                    <div ng-hide="isHidden" style="padding-bottom: 25px; margin-left: 20px;">
                        <trix-editor angular-trix ng-model="foo"></trix-editor>                     
                    </div>                  
                    <p style="font-size: 18px;">10. What would this allow you to achieve?</p>
                    <div ng-hide="isHidden" style="padding-bottom: 25px; margin-left: 20px;">
                        <trix-editor angular-trix ng-model="foo"></trix-editor>                     
                    </div>                  
                    <p style="font-size: 18px;">11. Who do you know that I should also be talking with? Who else cares a lot about <span style="color: blue;">{{ (task != null) ? task : '[job to be done]' }}</span>?</p>  
                    <div ng-hide="isHidden" style="padding-bottom: 25px; margin-left: 20px;">
                        <trix-editor angular-trix ng-model="foo"></trix-editor>                     
                    </div>                  
                    <p style="font-size: 18px;">12. I’ve learned so much from you! Can I ask for your feedback in the future?</p>
                    <div ng-hide="isHidden" style="padding-bottom: 25px; margin-left: 20px;">
                        <trix-editor angular-trix ng-model="foo"></trix-editor>                     
                    </div>                  
                </div>  
            </div>  
        </div>                         
    </form>
</div>
```

The show editor script is simple:

```
$scope.isHidden = true;
$scope.showEditor = function () {
  $scope.isHidden = $scope.isHidden ? false : true;
}
```

The copy to clipboard is third party called ng-clipboard. The show editor script is in the controller for this view.

Any ideas or suggestions please?

Thanks much.

Comment: have you checked console ? you have no errors?

Comment: Correct, no error. The click seems to happen, but nothing is highlighted and copied.

Comment: Anyone have anything they can add as to why this is happening?

Comment: i think the problem is in your app.js i think ... can you copy the controller and angular module you have

Comment: Can you elaborate on that as I am not seeing how it is in my app.js? The copy to clipboard function fires and does it thing, but if I click the ng-click="showEditor", then the copy to clipcoard function ceases to work.